# Install-Module attempts to download package using a wrong url

Tags: windows, powershell

There is a developer in my organisation that is unable to install powershell modules from our internal NuGet repository. He has the same PowershellGet version as I do, yet I have no such problem.

**His machine**

```
PS C:\> install-module xyz.ps.core -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Verbose
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='xyz.ps.core'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'xyz.ps.core'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xyz.ps.core'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'xyz.ps.core'.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Install-Module" on target "Version '1.0.19206.6' of module 'xyz.PS.Core'".
VERBOSE: The installation scope is specified to be 'CurrentUser'.
VERBOSE: The specified module will be installed in 'C:\Users\P124629\OneDrive - Ceridian HCM Inc\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'NuGet' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Downloading module 'xyz.PS.Core' with version '1.0.19206.6' from the repository 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='xyz.PS.Core'' for ''.
VERBOSE: InstallPackage' - name='xyz.PS.Core', version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\P124629\AppData\Local\Temp\1104224955'
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='xyz.PS.Core',
version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\P124629\AppData\Local\Temp\1104224955\xyz.PS.Core\xyz.PS.Core.nupkg',
uri='http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/'
VERBOSE: Downloading 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/package/xyz.PS.Core/1.0.19206.6'.
WARNING: Could not get response from query 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/package/xyz.PS.Core/1.0.19206.6'.
VERBOSE: Downloading package 'xyz.PS.Core' failed, please make sure 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/package/xyz.PS.Core/1.0.19206.6' is
accessable.
WARNING: MSG:SourceLocationNotValid «http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/»
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package 'xyz.PS.Core' failed to install.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Users\P12462...e.PS.Core.nupkg:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PackageFailedInstallOrDownload,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

PS C:\>
```

Notice the following line:

```
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='xyz.PS.Core',
version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\P124629\AppData\Local\Temp\1104224955\xyz.PS.Core\xyz.PS.Core.nupkg',
uri='http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/'
```

**My machine**

```
C:\> Install-Module xyz.PS.Core -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Verbose
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='xyz.PS.Core'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'xyz.PS.Core'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xyz.PS.Core'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'xyz.PS.Core'.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Install-Module" on target "Version '1.0.19206.6' of module 'xyz.PS.Core'".
VERBOSE: The installation scope is specified to be 'CurrentUser'.
VERBOSE: The specified module will be installed in 'C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'NuGet' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Downloading module 'xyz.PS.Core' with version '1.0.19206.6' from the repository
'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='xyz.PS.Core'' for ''.
VERBOSE: InstallPackage' - name='xyz.PS.Core',
version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\1058687073'
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='xyz.PS.Core',
version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\1058687073\xyz.PS.Core\xyz.PS.Core.nupkg',
uri='http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/Packages(Id='xyz.PS.Core',Version='1.0.19206.6')/Download'
VERBOSE: Downloading 'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/Packages(Id='xyz.PS.Core',Version='1.0.19206.6')/Download'.
VERBOSE: Completed downloading
'http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/Packages(Id='xyz.PS.Core',Version='1.0.19206.6')/Download'.
VERBOSE: Completed downloading 'xyz.PS.Core'.
VERBOSE: Hash for package 'xyz.PS.Core' does not match hash provided from the server.
VERBOSE: InstallPackageLocal' - name='xyz.PS.Core',
version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\1058687073'
VERBOSE: Catalog file 'xyz.PS.Core.cat' is not found in the contents of the module 'xyz.PS.Core' being installed.
VERBOSE: For publisher validation, current module 'xyz.PS.Core' with version '1.0.19206.6' with publisher name ''. Is this module
signed by Microsoft: 'False'.
VERBOSE: For publisher validation, using the previously-installed module 'xyz.PS.Core' with version '1.0.19206.6' under
'C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xyz.PS.Core\1.0.19206.6' with publisher name ''. Is this module signed by
Microsoft: 'False'.
VERBOSE: Module 'xyz.PS.Core' was installed successfully to path
'C:\Users\me\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xyz.PS.Core\1.0.19206.6'.
C:\>
```

Notice the following line:

```
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='xyz.PS.Core',
version='1.0.19206.6',destination='C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\1058687073\xyz.PS.Core\xyz.PS.Core.nupkg',
uri='http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/Packages(Id='xyz.PS.Core',Version='1.0.19206.6')/Download'
```

The difference is in the uri reported in the DownloadPackage phase:

- His machine - uri='http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/'
- My machine - uri='http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget/Packages(Id='xyz.PS.Core',Version='1.0.19206.6')/Download'

I do not understand how to troubleshoot this. He has the same PS modules installed as I do.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

(We use Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10)

**EDIT 1**

**His machine**

```
PS C:\> Get-PackageSource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
nuget.org                        NuGet            False      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
xyz                              PowerShellGet    True       http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    True       https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2


PS C:\> dir $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet


    Directory: C:\Users\P124629\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/25/2019   1:31 PM           5674 PSRepositories.xml


PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.592
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.592
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl, Get-...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Connect-WSMan, Disable-WSManCredSSP, Disconnect-WSMan, Enable-W...
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-PackagePro...
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapabilit...
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PSReadLi...


PS C:\>
```

**My machine**

```
C:\> Get-PackageSource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
Microsoft Visual Studio Offli... NuGet            False      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
NuGet.org                        NuGet            False      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
xyz                              PowerShellGet    True       http://devstatic.xyz.com/prdnuget/nuget
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    True       https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2


C:\> dir $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet


    Directory: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        4/12/2019   8:04 PM        1686528 NuGet.exe
-a----        7/26/2019  12:06 PM           5328 PSRepositories.xml


C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.592
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.592
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


C:\> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0.192... xyz.PS.Core                         {Add-ComputedFieldsToBuild, Add-xyzDatabaseIfNotFound, Assert-Elevated,...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider...}
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapability...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler...


C:\>
```

**The differences:**

1. My command prompt does not start with `PS`, his does. No idea if it is relevant.
2. I have an offline VS NuGet source, most likely does not matter.
3. I have nuget.exe in `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet`, he does not.
4. I do not have modules `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security` and `Microsoft.WSMan.Management`. Do not know if this is relevant.

Running procmon.exe and filtering to nuget.exe does not show that `Install-Module` runs it at all on my machine. Seems like it taps into the NuGet logic through nuget client dlls. To prove my point I renamed this file on my machine and `Install-Module` still works fine.

Comment: Is the `nuget.exe` version the same? `dir $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\NuGet.exe |% VersionInfo`

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, if you run `Get-PSRepository` do you have the same `SourceLocation` ? You can update this with `Register-PSRepository`

Comment: @jrider repository Location uri seems to be the same in both

Comment: Maybe `Get-PackageSource` update with `Register-PackageSource`

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, where the module path on one box was different than another. What I did to fix it was copy the nuget assemblies from `C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies\nuget` from my box over to the other box. This solved the issue. My box had a slightly newer version.